# Use VBA to get row data from powerpivot data?

Tags: vba, excel

I have imported a table in powerpivot, and were wondering if it's possible to get a row data from that source, by using VBA?

Lets say I import a table to my powerpivot datamodel from an external source,  that looks like below:

```
col1  col2
 1     tt
 2     tg
```

As the data is not on any sheet, but in the datamodel. Can I treat this datamodel table like an ordinary table with VBA. e.g. get a specific row or sum a column?

I have tried searching alot for this, but google results and excel seems to me abit messy. I have little experience in VBA, and basically have to idea how/if this is possible.

Comment: Yes there is, but first you need to provide your Pivot-Data structure, even a sample (or fake data) will do. Second, share with us your current code attempt

Comment: Can you also elaborate on what exactly you mean by 'Row Data' and also explain why you want to use VBA? E.g. "I am trying to do x. I need to use VBA because of y". I don't think I can do this natively within PowerPivot because of z".

Comment: @jeffreyweir I have edited my post with some more information. I hope it's sufficient.

Comment: See my answer below. You still haven't given any information on the specific thing you want to achieve. My answer basically says "Maybe, but why bother".

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the DataModel using CUBE functions, which can be called by VBA if you like. For examples, see https://powerpivotpro.com/2010/06/using-excel-cube-functions-with-powerpivot/

But the question is, why would you want to? To some degree, PowerPivot and the DataModel were designed to let you do complicated things right out of the box with little knowledge of code, instead of having to resort to VBA. Instead, just write whatever measures or calculated columns you need, and bring them into the worksheet via a PivotTable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you didn't give a lot of details around what you are doing, but I think the script below will be a good place to start.  modify to suit your needs.

```
Sub blah()
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Set pits = pt.PivotFields("???").PivotItems
For Each pit In pits
  If pit.Visible Then 'only acts on visible items
 pit.DataRange.ShowDetail = True
  'pit.name 'contains pivot item name that you could use to refer to a workbook to copy the data on the active sheet to, eg.;
 'ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Copy Workbooks(pit.Name).Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
 End If
Next pit
End Sub
```